# Linear Subspaces, Transversal intersections

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, differential-geometry

I was told that if $V$ and $W$ are two subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $V$ intersects W transversally means that $V+W = \mathbb{R}^n$.

My question is why? Is there a way to prove this? I feel like some type of inclusion/exclusion argument can be formed.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of [transversality for submanifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversality_(mathematics)) $V$ and $W$ of a smooth manifold $S$ is that at every point where $V$ and $W$ intersect, the tangent space of $S$ is the span of the tangent spaces of $V$ and $W$.  In the case of linear subspaces of a linear space, the tangent spaces of $V$, $W$ and $S$ are naturally identified with $V$, $W$ and $S$ themselves.

Answer (score 0):

For two submanifolds $S_1,S_2$ of a manifold $M$, $S_1\pitchfork S_2$ means that for all $x \in S_1 \cap S_2$, one has $T_xS_1+T_xS_2 = T_xM$. This is a definition.

Now take $M = \Bbb R^n$, $S_1 = V$ and $S_2 = W$. Then $V \pitchfork W$ means that for every $x \in V \cap W$ one has $$T_xV+T_xW = T_x\Bbb R^n.$$But for vector spaces, the tangent space at each point is the vector space itself, so $V \pitchfork W$ if and only if $V+W=\Bbb R^n$. There is no problem here because the intersection is never empty (there's at least $0$).